# Freeradius Server Configuration for Hotspot2.0/Passpoint

Tags: freeradius

I want to configure Freeradius server as a Passpoint using Hotspot2.0. I'm new to freeRADIUS server configuration, but I got it to configure Freeradius Server for 802.1x autentication and It's working normally for TLS (with certificate), TTLS (with certificate), PEAP and PWD. But I don't know how to configure Freeradius Server to use autentication for Passpoint/Hotspot2.0.

How can I install and configure this?

Comment: Are you talking about passpoint R1 or R2?

Comment: Passpoint R1after I will work with passpoint R2. Could you help me with this case?

Comment: R2 will be very different from R1. Only the profile is similar, but has more fields. The flow is totally different.

Comment: @rubens21 I am trying do deploy a simple Passpoint profile and I have managed to get it installed on the mobile phone and it is displayed among wifi networks. Somehow it won't associate with the AP. I suspect that I have maybe entered wrong FQDN and realm in the profile and WLC. In the profile I entered FQDN = xy.com, and Realm Name = xy.com. On the WLC side, I have configured Domain Name and Realm with the same values. Would this be correct? I know it doesn't reach authentication because I see no logs on AAA server so I suspect it has stucked in association stage.

Answer (score 0):

For Passpoint R1 release:

If your free radius is already working, there is no special configuration for that. All you need to do now is setting up correctly the profile (used by the device that will connect to the hotspot) and the AP (access point).

For Android devices, this example will guide you: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-passpoint#example_profile_oma-dm_xml

You will change the fields nested beneath `Realm` (username, password, EAPMethod) to match with whatever you have configured on your radius.

The key value, though, is `FQDN`. Your **AP** must have the same `FQDN` configured on the hotspot2.0 network. The device will match the profile `FQDN` with the SSID `FQDN`. And only when they match the device will use the profile to authenticate agains that AP.

You know when it is working when the friendly name show up in the wifi networks list.

The link above has the instructions to install the profile in the device.

Comment: How do you generate the X.509v3 CA certificate which is a "must have" for TTLS (https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-passpoint#file_composition)? Is this something I need to generate on RADIUS server for every user I create?